# MariaDB starts from cmd prompt but not as service

Tags: mariadb, windows

Attempting to start MariaDB as a service results in an error that says:

> Windows could not start the MariaDB service on Local Computer
>
> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control
> request in a timely fashion.

The error log does not show any errors after that start attempt but the server is not started. The error log looks completely normal and contains:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=1051746172,1051746172
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '.\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '.\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.8 started; log sequence number 1051746283; transaction id 199153
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from c:\ZZ-MariaDB_Data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2021-02-17  7:05:16 0 [Note] c:/mariadb/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.5.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2021-02-17  7:05:17 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210217  7:05:17
```

The INI file being used contains:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=c:/ZZ-MariaDB_Data
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation_server = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
[client]
plugin-dir=c:/MariaDB/lib/plugin
```

The `Path to executable` setting in Services is `c:/mariadb/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=C:/ZZ-MariaDB_Data/my.ini`.

If I run that from a command prompt the server starts properly and everything works as expected. Things only fail when I try to start it from Services.

Comment: your log looks normal and the server is startet

Comment: Agreed but it isn't really started and I am unable to connect to it. Very weird indeed which is why I posed the question.

Comment: try to restart it directly in services and see that your computer has nothing else open

Comment: I've done that. This is a 2in1 that starts nothing at boot to save on resources. I have tried starting it right after boot when nothing else is running to no avail.

Comment: Just did another reboot and tried it with the same result, won't start from Services.

Comment: this should procuce an error log also take look at the event viewer

Comment: Nothing in the error log except what was in my original question. I will have to take a look at the event viewer.

Comment: my guess ist that you have already a server installed, which log we see, and you try to start another one.

Comment: If that were the case it would have the same issue when I tried to start it from a command prompt. Which it doesn't.

Comment: mysql/mariadb write s alog when it can't start, your diesn't do it, so there is something very wrong, chekc the ini that will be used by the service and see where it tries to write his log.

Comment: I included the error log in the question. It hasn't changed at all. There were no errors in the Event Viewer. There were several informational entries that were a duplicate of what was in the error log.

Comment: mariadb writes his error logs in the datadirctory so that there a look

Comment: I encountered this with linux Mariadb. The issue was that the server startup process was taking longer than "allowed" by the OS. This ticket explained in for linux: https://groups.google.com/g/codership-team/c/dLDXE1U6llg

I would try increasing the service timeout setting in windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/system-management-components/service-not-start-events-7000-7011-time-out-error

Comment: I suppose you should check for this error: Error 1053 (https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion/) if that's indeed the case. I don't have much windows experience but felt like I recognised your issue. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: The service timeout setting was already at 60000 and even doubling it did not make a difference. I appreciate the pointer to that @MarkS. I also went through the list of things related to 1053 at the link you provided but, alas, no change in the situation.

Comment: (Unrelated)  128MB is much too small for the buffer_pool unless you ave only 1GB of RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the information @RickJames This machine is a 2in1 used for very light development work and never sees a load of any kind. That said it is also the value on my main machine so it sounds like I need to change it. What would a better value be?

Comment: @Dave - http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory